# Fallo al actualizar los repositorios con sudo apt update

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-server

Alguien me puede explicar por que no me deja actualizar los repositorios.

[image: Fallo a la hora de actualizar los repositorios]

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.